# Run Junit test cases only from Test suite and not individual class

Tags: java, junit, test-suite

I have setup an embedded mongo via flapdoodle (de.flapdoodle.embed).
Quite a lot of mongo operations hence i would like to run all of them as a suite and setup the mongo just once in testsuite.
Now when i run the test cases via mvn install , it seems to run the test cases individually.

Is there a way to run test cases only from suite and not as a class.

Answer (score 1):

[baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-filtering-tests) describes the use of JUnit 5 Tags, which are very well suited for your case.

You can mark tests with two different tags:

```
@Test
@Tag("MyMongoTests")
public void testThatThisHappensWhenThatHappens() {
}

@Test
@Tag("MyTestsWithoutMongo")
public void testThatItDoesNotHappen() {
}
```

And execute either set in a suite, e.g.

```
@IncludeTags("MyMongoTests")
public class MyMongoTestSuite {
}
```

In your case, the tests could be categorized by whether Mongo is in the application context or not. So, theoretically, it might be possible to create a [JUnit 5 Extension](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions) to add the tag. That would be the more complex solution though.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, I want the tests to be executed only from the suite. The Testcases class should not be executed on its own